# Regular expression that matches strings containing exactly 10 digits

Tags: regex

How would I write a regular expression (Python or Java) that matches strings that contain exactly 10 digits (0-9). I don't care if it contains any other characters, and the 10 digits do not have to be consecutive. For example, I want to following strings to match: "2fdf675&*85y989$%#0" and "3h2j9f88__+=123..54". Any ideas on how to go about doing this??

Answer (score 9):

Just try with:

```
^\D*(?:\d\D*){10}$
```

Comment: This requires them to start with a non-digit which doesn't meet the spec.

Comment: @HenrikN It starts with `\D*` so there can be no character other that digit in the beginning.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be clearer if you don't try to cram everything into one regex.  I don't know Java or Python, but here's what you could do in Perl:

```
$str =~ s/\D//g;  # Remove all non-digit characters
if ( length($str) == 10 ) ... # Must be left with 10 characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex and java code:

```
if (str.matches("(\\D*\\d){10}\\D*")) // FYI ^ and $ are implied in java
```

But in java here's an easier way to comprehend:

```
if (str.replaceAll("\\D", "").length() == 10)
```

This just removes all non-digits and checks the length of what's left.